# Laravel Homestead hangs at SSH auth method: private key on mac

Tags: macos, laravel, ssh, vagrant, homestead

I can't seem to get Homestead running. It hangs at SSH auth method: private key.

The Homestead VM starts. I can go to VirtualBox and open the terminal window and login with vagrant:vagrant.

I can't vagrant ssh, ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1:2204 or ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2204.

None of my folders show up in the VM, but the VirtualBox says they are mapped.

Every time I vagrant up, I get:

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> homestead-7: Fixed port collision for 80 => 8000. Now on port 2200.
==> homestead-7: Fixed port collision for 443 => 44300. Now on port 2201.
==> homestead-7: Fixed port collision for 3306 => 33060. Now on port 2202.
==> homestead-7: Fixed port collision for 5432 => 54320. Now on port 2203.
==> homestead-7: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2204.
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 2201 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 2202 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 2203 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2204 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...
==> homestead-7: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2204
    homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
    homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I replaced the homestead insecure private key with my key on my box. I see a lot of people get Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying..., but I don't get that far.

I'm on a mac 10.11.6

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you open virtualbox and check the status of the VM in virtualbox, has it completed booting or not ?

Comment: It is booted. I can open the VirtualBox VM screen and login as vagrant, password vagrant.

Answer (score 87):

I had the same problem on macOS 10.12 today, and lost 6 hours trying to find a fix. Finally, after several reinstallations, reboots, and trial and error, I somehow got it to work by following these steps...

1. Completely uninstall and reinstall Vagrant, VirtualBox, and Homestead.
2. Ensure the `homestead-7` box is shut down within the VirtualBox UI
3. Right-click the `homestead-7` box, and choose Settings
4. Click 'Network'
5. Under 'Adapter 1', which should be attached to NAT, click 'Advanced'
6. Tick the box beside 'Cable Connected'
7. Save settings, and reprovision Homestead with `vagrant up --provision`
8. Run `vagrant reload --provision` to reprovision the machine

That should be it! I was able to SSH in after this, but not able to view Homestead sites through the browser (even though I'd configured the `/etc/hosts` file), but a simple reboot of the Mac seemed to fix this.

Given I don't know what exactly caused this in the first place, this might just be a bit of luck for my case, but let me know how you get on.

Comment: Steps 3-6 solved the issue for me! You're a life saver @Jack!

Comment: Steps 3-6 solved the issue for me - but only temporarily. Destroying and recreating the vm requires steps 3-6 each time. Updating the Vagrantfile in my Homestead dir has been the best solution for me: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648#issuecomment-235282382

Comment: For me, I didn't have to reboot my mac after step 8, but noticed that the virtual machine is stuck at login. I just have to provide the default username and password (vagrant/vagrant) and after I am able to access my sites! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.1, and steps 3-6 do the trick.  The link posted by @DanielSposito (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648#issuecomment-235282382) is on the money, just put in into your Vagrantfile.

Comment: I logged in just to say thank you! 
using laravel 5.4 vagrant 1.9.5 virtualbox 5.1.22

Comment: I hit this problem as well, but this spurred me to update to latest VirtualBox and things are looking good. I'm actually testing out Nomad, not Homestead.

Comment: This one does not apply anymore.  Homestead come already configured with the Cable option.  The answer below fixed my issue:  Open VirtualBox UI and enter the virtual machine.  Press Enter key to make system continue to boot.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open VirtualBox UI and enter the virtual machine.
2. press Enter key to make system continue to boot.

And then you can see the vagrant up going on.

Comment: I love you. This answer should be marked as an accepted answer.

Comment: Thx, steven. This one SHOULD really marked as the accepted answered.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem. I enabled Vt-x in the bios and it cleared it.

Comment: Windows 10 user here, did the same thing and it worked

Comment: My bios reported it as "Intel Virtualisation Technology". Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Replaced motherboard, and started having this issue...   this was it for me too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Vagrant 2.1.2

`vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up --provision` worked for me.

I have noticed that it usually happens when new version of vagrant released

Comment: Even if this "solves" the problem, the bug might reappear as it did to my vbox. This is the last measure, and should be warned.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem and you will have to redownload the box again

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Windows, you have done everything here and still have trouble, maybe this is the solution you need.

Open the Command Prompt as an administrator. Type the `bcdedit` command. You may find `hypervisorlaunchtype Auto`. If that is the case, type `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` to turn it off. Reboot and try again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After 3 evenings of troubleshooting, this ended up being the fix for me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Nothing here worked for me. I got into the situation of `SSH auth method: private key` because my mac black screened and crashed.

All that worked for me was a `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up --provision`. Beware this will of course trash anything in your VM. but you should be using ephemeral principles anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Enable "Virtualization Technology" in BIOS settings

Answer (score 3):

I had to do a fsck. (disclaimer, I typed the commands from memory)

1. Open VirtualBox UI and enter the virtual machine.
2. If you see (initramfs), type exit
3. fsck /dev/mapper/vagrant-vg-root -y
4. reboot

Go back to your normal terminal and try a:

```
vagrant halt
vagrant up
```

For me, things were back to normal from here.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks Dude. in my case i run fsck /dev/mapper/homestead-vg-root -y

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me all of a sudden after working fine for a while using Homestead v6.4 with virtualbox. To fix, Open VirtualBox - if using - and check the logs there.

I found instructions to manually fsck a directory which fixed the issue

Your directory will likely be different, but mine was

```
fsck /dev/mapper/homestead--vg-root
```

And then select y to fix all of the errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `vagrant up` from **CMD**  with admin rights

Answer (score 0):

If you're still stuck, here's something you can quickly rule out:

For me the issue was too little video memory, for some reason in Virtual Box my video memory was set to 4mb, the minimum is 12mb, I set it to 24mb (with vm off) and ran `vagrant up` again, and it fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after installing Docker Desktop for Windows.
The two aren't compatible.

run Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor

this will disable hypervisor.

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
to enable.

I've found that now Homestead takes a long time to boot, Open VMBox, select homestead and click on Show (green button).  Wait until you have the homestead login prompt.
Then go back & you can run vagrant ssh into Homestead.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this as of March 2024 with the following steps:

1. Ideally, capture a backup of your database.
2. Destroy the VM inside VirtualBox: Right click VM > Remove > Delete all files.
3. Run `vagrant up`.