# Homestead Vagrant stuck on SSH connect

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

When I try to boot up Laravel Homestead on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.12.3) it gets stuck on:

```
homestead-7: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
homestead-7: SSH username: vagrant
homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key
```

And it will eventually time-out.

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

This is what my vagrant box displays:

[image: This is what my Vagrant box displays]

My *Homestead.yaml*:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

I'm running Vagrant 1.9.1 with VirtualBox 5.1.14.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you recently upgraded your vagrant box? I had the same issue.. I had to completely nuke my mac and start again....

Comment: No this was my first install of Homestead.

Comment: are you on osx or windows?

Comment: Im on Osx 10.12.3

Comment: Could it be permission issue on either your public key file? If i remember correctly its something to do with unsecured keys.. but i cant remember the fix.

Comment: Ill try creating a new key for homestead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Apparently I had to enable "Cable Connection" on my VM.

[Laravel Homestead hangs at SSH auth method: private key on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968297/laravel-homestead-hangs-at-ssh-auth-method-private-key-on-mac)

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7648#issuecomment-235282382