# What's the use of authorize and keys options in Homestead.yaml file?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I noticed that I can provision a box, and ssh to it even after commenting out both options in `Homestead.yaml`, as in:

```
# authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

# keys:
#     - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Are they necessary at all? I suppose that they let me specify public/private keys for `vagrant ssh`, but as I understand such pair is generated by vagrant anyway (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471542/cant-ssh-to-vagrant-vms-using-the-insecure-private-key-vagrant-1-7-2)). What is the actual need for those settings then?

The reason I'd like to know that is that I keep running into an issue where I cannot ssh into a box as `vagrant up` keeps hanging up on `homestead-7: SSH auth method: private key` (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40968297/laravel-homestead-hangs-at-ssh-auth-method-private-key-on-mac) question). With authorize and keys options commented out I haven't had problem with `vagrant up` so far.

Answer (score 0):

SSH keys are used for passwordless authentication. In order to use this, you will need to run `ssh-keygen` then press enter for all defaults. Once this has been generated, then Homestead will use that to ssh into the VM and run the necessary commands.

If you are running Windows 10, then you will need to install an SSH client. This could be done in various ways such as GIT Bash, Putty, OpenSSH and WSL. If you comment the lines out, then it's likely it will be logging into the machine using the default username/password combo given to the machine.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but my question is specifically about the purpose of `authorize` and `keys` settings in `Homestead.yaml`. I am familiar with SSH authentication. Just trying to debug the occasional problems with connecting to the box (they are pretty random, and usually a full system reboot is required as a workaround).